# Does "left: -10000%" take significantly more processing/rendering power than "left: -100%"?

Tags: css, css-position

For an absolutely positioned element, does setting it's `left` property to `-10000%` take significantly more processing or rendering power than setting it to `-100%`?

Comment: point. I deleted it. I don't think I'm awake yet :D

Answer (score -1):

Rendering performance can be affected by asking the browser to draw very large blocks. Hiding an element -10000% away seems overkill, but deep inside I hope browsers have some collective smartness and don't bother drawing anything that's placed in negative viewport space :)

Wild guess, but in case you are trying to hide text this technique works well:

```css
.hide-text {
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Elements of `height: 0` will be skipped by some screenreaders and probably googlebot, like `display: none` or `font-size: 0`. Use `height: 1px; width: 1px`. [Source](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility)

Comment: Edited my answer to remove `height: 0`. Thanks for pointing it out @amdouglas, makes sense.